# how to create a WebClient using OAuth2 to communicate between 2 resource servers

Tags: spring-webclient

I have tried Web client in resource server but I am getting 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' error.

I was expecting to communicate between the two resource servers endpoints to transer data. I am using Spring OAuth2 server